# Which of the followings are correct: (Analytic Function)

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

**Which of the followings are correct:**

[image]

**My thought:** $g(z)=\dfrac{2}{3+z}$ is analytic on $\mathbb C-\{3\}.$ Also $f=g$ on $\{\dfrac{1}{n}\}$ which has a limit point $0$ on $\mathbb D.$ So by identity theorem $f=g$ on any domain contained in the domains of the definitions of both $f$ and $g.$

**1 is true:** $f(0)=\dfrac{2}{3+0}=\dfrac{2}{3};$ **4 is false:** $f(z)=\dfrac{2}{3+z};$ **3 & 2 are false:** $3,-3$ is outside the domain of definition of $f;$ e.g. let $f(z)=\dfrac{2}{3+z}~\forall~|z|\leq 1$ and  $f(z)=1~\forall~|z|>1.$

Please tell me whether I'm right or wrong!

Comment: @Clayton: What's wrong with the reasoning for $1?$

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK, but for the fourth you would maybe have to motivate that $f(z)$ is defined on the entire unit disc (by for example noting that $3+z\ne0$ there).